# AppleScript syntax all messed up, how to re-build?

Tags: applescript

One of my AppleScripts hasn't been working for a few weeks, so I decided to investigate why. Upon opening it in the Script Editor of OS X, I was kind of surprised to see the code formatted [like this](https://pastebin.com/mmgAwuDf). Snippet:

```
FasdUAS 1.101.10ˇˇˇˇ
k
lˇ˛ˇ˛Get battery level±    "Get battery level
ˇ˝
l|ˇ¸ˇ˚
Q|
ˇ˙
ks
r

Iˇ˘ˇ¯
ˇ˘.sysoexecTEXTˇˇÄTEXT
m±Pioreg -w0 -l | grep "\"MaxCapacity\" = "ˇ¯
oˇ˜ˇ˜0maxcapacitymaxCapacity
r
lˇˆˇı
n
4ˇÙ
ˇÙ
cwor
m
ˇÛˇÛˇˇ
oˇÚˇÚ0maxcapacitymaxCapacityˇˆˇı
oˇÒˇÒ0maxlevelmaxLevel
r !
Iˇ"ˇÔ
ˇ.sysoexecTEXTˇˇÄTEXT
```

As you can see, a lot of weird characters that pretty much make this script impossible to use, and impossible to "fix", syntax-wise.

What can cause something like this to happen and how can I rectify it? It will take me hours to rebuild it manually.

Comment: This is the text representation of a compiled script rather than the source. Was the original script saved as read-only?

Comment: I don’t think it was. It was working fine and i Even modified it in one stage. Anything that can be done?

Comment: You could try `osadecompile` in the shell. However if the script was saved as read-only/run-only you are trapped.

Comment: decomplie is indeed returning `rrOSAScriptError (-1753)`. I don't understand how is this possible, I don't remember ever saving it as read-only/run-only...I don't even know how that's done.